# Netbeans Theme: adjusting colour of HTML parameter values

Tags: netbeans

Where can I change the background colour of HTML parameter values in NetBeans? 
I don't understand why it gets highlighted.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyVKo.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parameter the syntax color and highlights in :

> Tools --> Options --> Fonts & Colors

In pane `Syntax`, choose HTML then choose categories you want and custom it.

For highlights, go in pane `Highlighting`.