# Where can I find a white theme for netbeans 7?

Tags: netbeans-7

It's hard to find a nice theme for NetBeans 7 and each theme I have found is black.
Where can I found a really nice white theme for making PHP / HTML / Javascript / CSS into NetBeans?
Thanks!

Comment: I think a blue theme like the color of the Anna hair would be better.

Comment: the default Netbeans theme is white.

Comment: Yes, but the color syntax and original font is really ugly for php/html/etc...
I just want to get a global better theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found for you the best theme for Netbeans 7 :

http://net.tutsplus.com/freebies/themes/netbeans-twilight-theme/

edit:
If you don't found a nice theme, just edit the color language as it's said here : [Netbeans Theme: adjusting colour of HTML parameter values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249368/netbeans-theme-adjusting-colour-of-html-parameter-values)

Answer (score 2):

Build your own @ http://www.wordfraud.net/themebuilder/